# Can the Jojo skin for Big Band be earned in online multiplayer with friends?

Tags: skullgirls

I am trying to earn the Jojo skin for Big Band. Can I do it in multiplayer with friends? Or must I do it in more "legitimate" ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to various forum posts I've been seeing (like [this one](http://skullheart.com/index.php?threads/the-palettes-of-skullgirls.478/page-30)), it looks like the only real restriction is that it can't be earned in Training mode. Thus, having your friends help you earn this palette should be viable. Even better, according to some users, you can even unlock this palette in local versus mode.

> Most achievements don't unlock from stuff you do in training mode, so the same might be the case for this palette. I had it unlock by grinding it out in local versus, so try that.
>
> i just tried this out. got it in local vs on win #26. looks very cool.